# preprocessing markup

Tags: 7, theming

I have a file called template.php and inside the template file I have a preprocessor but I have two problems I don't know if the preprocessor is loading
and if the code in the file is right.

The code inside the file is

function template_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
        kpr($vars);  //Uncomment to output the $vars array.
   }

At this stage all I am trying to do is see if I can get the node to give me some feedback but I get nothing. The nodes I am testing this on does have three fields

Comment: Version numbers and location of template.php is required to answer your question.

Comment: drupal7 and themename->templates->template.php

Answer (score 2):

Your template file should reside in the `sites/all/themes/mytheme/ directory`. Not in the `templates` subdirectory. Furthermore, your preprocess function should be named `mytheme_preprocess_field()`. Be sure to clear your cache.

You might want to perhaps also look at the [Devel Themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module. It should provide information on the preprocess function being used and so on. I'm unsure how well it works with Drupal 7. But it's worth your time if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, definitely get the [Devel Theme](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module. It can be a great help in Drupal 7 when digging through the arrays on that page so you won't make any mistakes. It will give a simple list of the field names you can then call.